# Making a Django page visible only to confirmed emails

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I'm trying to add a feature to my site where a certain part of the site can be used only by users who confirmed their email account.

I found a solution, but it's not working.
Here is what i did:
I have been suggested to add a separate model for this:

```
class account_emailconfirmation(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

        @property
        def has_verified_email(self):
            return self.user.emailaddress_set.filter(verified=True,primary=True).exists()
```

And this is what the template looks like:

```
{% extends "main/header.html" %}

{% if user.account_emailconfirmation.has_verified_email %}
{% block content %}
<style>

</style>

<body>



<div> <p>Here goes a bunch of features</p> </div>       



</body>

{% endblock %}

{% else %}

<p> Your email is ot confirmed </p>
{% endif %}
```

But it's not working, since i can see the page even without having to confirm my email.

Here is what my db looks like:

There is a table called `account_emailconfirmation`, then there is an index, `verified`, that will give `0` when the account is not verified, `1` when it is verified.

Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write this:

```
{% extends "main/header.html" %}

{% block content %}
{% if user.profile.has_verified_email %}
<style>

</style>

<body>



<div> <p>Here goes a bunch of features</p> </div>       



</body>

{% else %}

<p> Your email is ot confirmed </p>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#onetoonefield) attribute of the `account_emailconfirmation.user` one to one field

```
{% if user.account_emailconfirmation.has_verified_email %}
```

Side note, you should capitalize your classes:

```
class EmailConfirmation(models.Model):
```

I assume the `account_` portion is for the app. You don't need that, you know which app the model is in.

Comment: Hey! Yes, i was already using the related name, i just made a mistake when writing the code here! I'm gonna capitalize my classes. Concerning account_, that is the name of the table! Anyway, as @vyacheslav pointed out, i only add to put my if statement AFTER the block content, and not before. Thanks for your help!